# Simple django unit tests giving 404 - What is the correct setup procedure?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm a ways down my Django project and have decided unit tests are a good idea.  I am trying to write a simple unit test around a view, but I'm getting `<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /index was not found on this server.</p>` from the response.  Why is that happening?

Here is my unit test..

```
from django.test import TestCase

class BookerIndexTests(TestCase):
    def test_anonymous_request(self):
        response = self.client.get('booker:index')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Within my `urls.py`, I have this line for my index: `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),`

Am I missing a setup step here?  Why is this basic unit test throwing a 404 error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman pointed out, you can't use a pattern name directly in `client.get()`. If you want to use the pattern name rather than the paths themselves, you can use `reverse`. You code could look like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class BookerIndexTests(TestCase):
    def test_anonymous_request(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('booker:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

This is typically what I do in my test suites because I prefer to use the pattern names over the paths.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a URL pattern name to `client.get()`, rather than an actual path. You need to pass the actual index path, which is - according to that urlconf - "/".

Comment: Thanks.  Isn't it more test-friendly to pass the URL pattern name, since we won't have to modify all our tests if the actual url path changes in the future?